# CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD doesn't work when setting after project name

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I'm setting:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

in my cmake, however in visual studio 2019 it's not setting the standard correctly and defaulting to C++14.

If I set it like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++17")
```

Then it works. I'm not sure why this is the case as I'd like to not use the above method.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT ANSWER:
It seems like you have to set the project before the version like so:

```
project(TradingEngine CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

where I had it like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) 

project(TradingEngine CXX)
```

Comment: Did you set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD ` before creating the targets?

Comment: Yes, I did that in the main CMAKE_LISTS.txt file. The only thing above that is the VERSION of cmake that is expected.

Comment: @nemo I found that both of the two methods work indeed. Do you mean `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` doesn't work when setting after project name?

Comment: Regarding your answer: the first two lines of your top-level CMakeLists.txt _really ought to_ be `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)` (or whatever version you're actually using to develop and test) followed by `project(MyProj)`. Nothing before, nothing in between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMAKE won't add -std=c++20 flag despite standard being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75814454/cmake-wont-add-std-c20-flag-despite-standard-being-set)