# Why won't CMake add a language standard compilation flag to a target via CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD created before the definition of that variable?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I'm using `cmake version 3.22.1` and `c++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0`

and a very minimalistic `CMakeLists.txt`

I can't make CMAKE use C++20.

Setting

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
```

leads to no flag being present in the output.

> [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o
> /usr/bin/c++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o -c /media/ruby/SHARED/Diverses/Programmieren/cmake_tutorial/tutorial.cxx

Using this however:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++20")
```

> [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o
> /usr/bin/c++   -std=c++20 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/Executable.dir/tutorial.cxx.o -c /media/ruby/SHARED/Diverses/Programmieren/cmake_tutorial/tutorial.cxx

works flawlessly. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The full CMakeLists.txt

```
# First line, every project needs it
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

# Specifies the name of the project
project(example_project)

# Tell cmake to create executable using specified source code files
add_executable(Executable tutorial.cxx)

# This part adds the flag correcly
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++20")

# This does not
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
```

Comment: Maybe your default standard is already c++20?

Comment: @OlafDietsche its not, unfortunately. `tutorial.cxx` features a `char8_t`, which is only present from C++20. When the flag isn't present, the build generates a compiler error, as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The docs for `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) state:

> Default value for [`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) target property if set when a target is created.

You set the default-initializer variable ***after*** the creation of the target you wanted it to apply for. Move the varible definition to go ***before*** the creation of the target you want it to apply to. Or just use [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html).

setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` after the creation of a target works because `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` works differently. See [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html).

> The flags in this variable will be passed to the compiler before those in the per-configuration [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) variant, and before flags added by the [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) or [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) commands.

The contents of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` are copied to a target property at the time the target is created/defined, and that target property does not watch `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to mirror changes. `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is managed as its own thing and is added to the final list of compile flags for a source file when that final list is created.

Answer (score 2):

Order is important, this doesn't work:

```
add_executable(Executable tutorial.cxx)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
```

And this one works as expected:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
add_executable(Executable tutorial.cxx)
```